# Why do the GS and LOC indicators blink?

Tags: boeing-737, flight-instruments, ils

So, the question is in the title. Specifically referring to this [video](https://youtu.be/JdzOwDCZRYo). At around timestamp 2:10 in the video, you can see the GS and LOC indicators blink. Why does it blink?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From this copy of the flight manual for the 737](http://www.737ng.co.uk/737NG%20POH.pdf):

> **Glide Slope Pointer and Deviation Scale**
>
> ...
>
> At low radio altitudes, with autopilot engaged, the scale turns amber
>   and the pointer flashes to indicate excessive glide slope deviation.
>
> Each pilot’s deviation alerting system self-tests upon becoming armed
>   at 1500 feet radio altitude. This self-test generates a two second G/S
>   deviation alerting display on each attitude indicator.

And for the localizer

> **Localizer Pointer and Deviation Scale**
>
> ...
>
> At low radio altitudes, with autopilot engaged, the scale turns amber
>   and the pointer flashes to indicate excessive localizer deviation.
>
> Below 1,000 feet AGL, with LNAV engaged and LOC armed, the localizer
>   scale turns amber and the pointer flashes if the localizer is not
>   captured.
>
> Each pilot’s deviation alerting system self-tests upon
>   becoming armed at 1500 feet radio altitude. This self-test generates a
>   two second LOC deviation alerting display on each attitude indicator.

What is interesting is that the pilot seems to be right on slope and right on the localizer so I would presume it is NOT flashing as a result of excessive deviation.

Comment: Is that passing a marker beacon?

Comment: I think it's the self test as it passes 1500 ft RA.